# Did Loki steal the Tesseract, again?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok, loki, avengers-infinity-war

In Thor : Ragnarok towards the climax we see Loki entering the Asgard vault to put Surtur's crown into the Eternal flame.

But, there is a moment he pauses to take a look at the Tessaract. Did he just look at it, or did he steal it? This might also explain the large ship that intercepted them in the post credits scene (It could be Thanos following the Infinity Stone.)

I know no one knows what will be happening in the MCU further, but is there any such plot element in the comics (as I have not read much of them)?

Comment: We don't know. There's certainly no good reason for him not to have done, since it was sat right there in front of him.

Comment: My main question was whether is there any plot element- relating to Loki stealing the Tessract and Thanos intercepting them - in the comics since Infinity war has already happened in there.

Comment: @Skooba I saw a Comicon trailer in which the Guardians arrive in lot of debris floating in mid space and then Thor hits their windshield.So I thought it might be something about it.

Comment: @Skooba - Since the comic-con trailer has been publicly broadcast (albeit to a small audience) this is not a future-works policy question. I've withdrawn my close vote and answered the question.

Comment: @Valorum not that I think this major of a plot point would change so VTRO from me now, but I wonder with how much trailer materials ends up not making the final cut how that affects our policy (I might raise it on meta).

Comment: Infinity gauntlet and Infinity War from the comics are VERY different than what is being set up in the MCU.

Comment: No, he left it there to be demolished WHAT DO YOU THINK?

Comment: Is it really stealing if he should have been the rightful owner all along?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Yes, he did.

Based on footage that was shown at the SDCC Comic-Con (low quality copy [here](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x5vzdu9)), Loki is seen presenting the Tesseract to a shadowy figure much larger than himself. A minute or so later, we see Thanos wearing a glove with a glowing blue stone embedded in the knuckle.

So either Loki recovered the Tesseract from the wreckage of Asgard before boarding Thor's ship (unlikely) or he took it from the vault when he walked past it (highly likely).

[image]

---

Studio head Kevin Feige left little to the imagination in an interview with Slashfilm

> **SF: And we also see Loki in that area. He walks by the Tesseract.  When that planet blows up at the end, I assume that particular
> Infinity Stone is not on that planet.**
>
> **Feige:** *You were at Comic-Con, right? Did you see the Infinity War footage?*
>
> **Yeah, and Loki had the cube in his possession in the footage.**
>
> **Feige:** *The story I’m about to tell you is nothing about the mythology, just about filmmaking, I was just talking to Hiddleston
> about this. When he shot that, he had the Surtur skull and he walked
> by and he looked at [the tessaract] but then he kept walking. And he
> left frame. And it was like that in the cut for a while. And nobody
> remembered the moment. It didn’t register with anybody. So we recut it
> so that Loki looks at it and then we cut away. When we showed that
> cut, it registered with people who knew what it was. Did he take it?
> He stopped, what does that mean?  Which was exactly what we wanted the
> audience to do.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Kevin Feige Answers Your Lingering ‘Thor: Ragnarok’ Spoiler Questions](http://www.slashfilm.com/thor-ragnarok-spoiler-questions/)</sup></sub>

Comment: Yes this is what I was talking of.Thanks for the answer.

Comment: IIRC only the SDCC footage leaked, not the D23 footage.

Comment: spoilers are needed for all of this :P

Comment: @Skooba - I'm reasonably certain we don't need spoilers for a trailer.

Comment: Abandoning an Infinity Stone on a planet that was being destroyed would be gross negligence of staggering proportion.  Loki did the right thing taking the stone, and he did the right thing telling Thor he took it.  Which he did do, just by being Loki.  "You got the Tessaract, right?"  "no brother, I never thought of that, we should go back for it!"  "Good, good, keep it safe."

Comment: @Harper - Unless that;s the means by which Thanos tracked the Asgardian ship, in which case Loki shoulda taken that thing and flown in the opposite direction

Comment: The interview doesn't say that Loki took the Tesseract, but that it was filmed so that the audience understands Loki took it. Could be some misdirection to prepare a twist in Infinity War. That's highly unlikely but what if Loki gives a fake Tesseract to Thanos? Do we know for sure that the fake Infinity Glove was made by Odin? After all, Loki is the only one that knows the whole Thanos threat, is shown not to be completely a bad guy by the end of Ragnarok and is the ultimate trickster.

Comment: @Taladris - Feige doesn't deny that Loki took the tesseract and asks the interviewer saw the footage from comic-con. That seems like proof-positive to me. Honestly I only put the interview in for completeness. The visual answers the question entirely.

Comment: @Taladris oh, be realistic.  Galactic badasses like Thanos or Yondu would never fall for the old "fake infinity stone" trick...

Comment: Now that Infinity War is out, we can confirm for sure that Loki took the Tesseract, again.