# Who are the current owners of the Infinity Stones in the MCU before the beginning of Infinity War?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, infinity-stones

Who owns the Infinity Stones in the MCU currently, i.e. before the beginning of the events of *Avengers: Infinity War*. Who has owned these Infinity Stones up until now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Infinity Stones have we seen so far in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64573/which-infinity-stones-have-we-seen-so-far-in-the-marvel-cinematic-universe)

Comment: Your previous question asking this was closed as a duplicate. Why do you think this one isn't a duplicate as well?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin The answer is slightly different than the target so I don't think it is a dupe

Comment: I think they're related but I don't think this is a duplicate because it's asking specifically about the time when Infinity War starts. Some of these have changed hands several times through the course of the films

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I just asked a question that was closed moments ago as duplicate of this question. So I narrowed my question down to owners.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin If anything, that question is a duplicate of thise one, as the broader question, this one should remain open.

Comment: @Paul I've removed the infinity war tag because this question is not about the events of that film but events before then.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: sure, although given that it’s asking about the state of play *right before* the events of that film, it feels like it’s related to that film.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite the key word there is "related", it's related to more films than we have tag space for!

Comment: @Edlothiad: sure, we can’t tag it with the 18 films that it wants an Infinity Stone Summary of. But we *can* tag it with the one film that’s actually mentioned in the question, that defines the scope of the question. If that’s not related, I don‘t know what is.

Comment: What do you mean "own"? Ownership is a legal status, and as far as I'm aware, the infinity stones are not typically subjected to normal rules of law. They're constantly stolen, coveted, hidden, and fought over due to their extraordinary power. There doesn't appear to be any sense of the stone rightly belonging to anyone. (I.e., the heroes who value law and order wouldn't return it to anyone that had some rightful claim to it if they possessed one.) Do you just mean "possess"?

Comment: @jpmc26 I think it is quite clear the OP means possess.

Comment: As in daemonology, possession is nine tenths of the lore. Law. Whatever. :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The [Infinity Stones](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Soul_Stone) have changed hands various times over the history of the MCU, some more than others.
<sub>(click all images to embiggen)</sub>

## These are the current and previous owners:

<sub>(source film in brackets, index at bottom of answer)</sub>

### Space Stone is owned by Asgard/Loki

Excluding all details (Trailers, interviews, theories based on evidence, etc.) from Infinity War, the Space Stone is believed to be destroyed by Surtur along with Asgard.

[image]

Including the extra details, [this Q&A](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/174154/68872) as Loki having stolen it from the vaults in Asgard before Surtur destroyed Asgard, and as shown in [this image from the trailer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3022.jpg).

Previous Owners include: Heimdall (AV), Loki (AV), S.H.I.E.L.D. (post-CA:TFA), Howard Stark (CA:TFA), Hydra (CA:TFA), "Church Keeper" (CA:TFA)

### Mind Stone is owned by Vision

The Avengers claims the Mind Stone from Ultron when they steal the cradle with Ultron's new body in it. Thor, Stark, and Bruce Banner grant the body life, creating Vision.

[image: Vision and the mind stone]

Previous owners include: Ultron (AV:AOU), Avengers (AV:AOU), Hydra (AV: AOU), S.H.I.E.L.D (AV), Loki (AV)...

### Reality Stone is owned by Taneleer Tivan (The Collector)

The Asgardians gave the Aether (and the Reality Stone) to The Collector for safe-keeping after defeating Malekith.

[image: The Collector with the Reality Stone]

Previous owners include: Asgard (T:TDW), Malekith (T:TDW), Jane Foster (T:TDW)...

### Power Stone is owned by Nova Corps

The Power Stone is given to the Nova Corps for safe-keeping after Peter Quill catches the unprotected Stone and destroys Ronan the Accuser.

[image: Power Stone in the Orb]

Previous owners include: Ronan the Accuser (GotG), Star-Lord (GotG)...

### Time Stone is owned by Doctor Strange

Doctor Strange owned the gem as part of the Eye of Agamotto, the stone was used by Doctor Strange, first to aid him in his learning of sorcery, then in his final fight against Kaecilius and Dormammu. It is unknown how long the Stone has stood as part of the Eye on a pedestal in Kamar-Taj.

[image: Eye of Agamotto]

Previous owners include: Cagliostro (DS), Agamotto (DS)

### Soul Stone is Unknown

The location of the Soul Stone is revealed for the first time in *Avengers: Infinity War*

---

Key to films:

- CA:TFA = Captain America: The First Avenger
- AV = Avengers
- AV:AOU = Avengers: Age of Ultron
- T:TDW = Thor: The Dark World
- GotG = Guardians of the Galaxy
- DS = Doctor Strange

Comment: When did Heimdall own the Space stone in The Avengers. He wasn't even in the movie no?

Comment: @KharoBangdo It was _technically_ in the [Thor: The Dark World Prelude](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Thor:_The_Dark_World_Prelude) comics which were set before during and after _The Avengers_ hence why it's noted down as _The Avengers_. [Thor entrusted it to Heimdall to repair the bifrost](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_WG_KzZTPHa45DWSB4HmBSJkaEF6_7tbpP8CEqLXireBpcjwrwh0HlH4KZY6M7iO_gTaj49I8kxO-chEPkeV4ynD9M7pRrut3ucuYk7nK3tGlgDBeHiEnTJi6zBYvcd19SzMsQ=s1600).

Answer (score 26):

### Space Stone

Last seen in *Thor: Ragnarok* on Asgard inside the vaults.

[image: Thor with the Tessaract]

However, as pointed out in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/174158/58193) it is likely that Loki stole it before the destruction of Asgard.

### Mind Stone

Last seen as part of Vision, was given to him in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* and has stayed with him since.

[image: Vision with the mind stone]

### Reality Stone

Last seen with The Collector in *Thor: The Dark World*.

[image: The Collector with the Aether]

### Power Stone

Last scene in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol 1* when the guardians give the stone to the Nova Corps on Xandar for safe keeping.

[image: Power Stone in a vault on Xandar]

### Time Stone

Last seen with Doctor Strange in *Thor: Ragnarok*.

[image: Doctor Strabnge with the Eye of Agamotto]

### Soul Stone

The location of this stone has yet to be revealed before the film.

Answer (score 9):

## Pre- *Avengers: Infinity War*:

In order with reference to this [image](https://geeks.media/where-is-the-soul-stone)*

### Space Stone

[image: Loki]
**Owner: Loki**

During the final events of *Thor: Ragnarok*, Loki takes the Tesseract from Asgard. This is supported by the official *Avengers: Infinity War* trailer.

---

### Mind Stone

[image: Vision]

**Owner: Vision**

As of *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, Vision is the owner and host of the Mind Stone, previously taken from Loki's Chitauri Scepter.

---

### Reality Stone

[image: Aether]

**Owner: The Collector**

The events of *Thor: The Dark World* show the Aether being handed over to the Collector to be kept in his museum.

---

### Power Stone

[image: Power]
**Owner: The Nova Corp**

After the battle against Ronan in *Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol 1*, the Guardians hand over the Power Stone to the Nova Corp for safekeeping.

---

### Time Stone

[image: Time]
**Owner: Doctor Strange**

As seen in *Doctor Strange*, the Time Stone is encased within the Eye of Agamotto.

---

[image: Infinity Stones]

As of Marvel's *Avengers: Infinity War* trailer, we know that Thanos has the Space Stone, Power Stone, and possibly the Mind Stone (from Vision) as well. All this is made clear in the movie. Finally...

## Disclaimer: From this point onwards, this is a major spoiler until Infinity War has been released in all countries and regions.

### Soul Stone

> **Owner: Red Skull**
>  
> Pre-events of *Avengers: Infinity War*, we know that in *Captain America: The First Avenger* the Red Skull 'disappears' upon holding the Tesseract.
>  
> Currently, the plot gap between that incident and seeing Red Skull in *Infinity War* has not (visibly) been filled, but Red Skull is seen surrendering the Soul Stone to Thanos through the sacrifice of a loved one.

---

## Post- *Avengers: Infinity War*:

> **Infinity Stones**
>  
> Owner: Thanos
>  
> He has them all in his gauntlet by the end of the movie.

---

- *The final location of the Tesseract may not be accurate in the image.*

  Post-script: I have attempted to upload an image showing the last viewer location of each of the Stones, all save the Mind Stone.

Comment: Note: I have watched Avengers: Infinity War in the cinema already. Please note that the content within the spoilers are legitimate. Click at your own risk!

Comment: Here's the source for that last picture: https://twitter.com/mantia/status/795035273415434240

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Spoiler alert dude!

Answer (score 0):

1)Space stone (tesseract) is with Loki after he took it in thor : Ragnarok .

2)Mind stone is in vision’s forehead as of captain america civil war.

3)Reality stone (eather) is with the collector in his ruined home of knowhere.

4)Power stone is been protected in Xandar by the nova empire.

5) Time stone(eye of agomotto) is with the Masters of the Mystic Arts (namely Wong) at Kamar-Taj in Nepal.

6) Soul stone is not in anyone’s possession…yet.

Okay so I want to add that : 
The Infinity Stones are too powerful to be owned by someone.

In the comics, there was a cosmic being before the universe existed - Nemesis. When she died, her powers were too much to be destroyed. So they were transformed into the Infinity Gems.

In the movies, there were six singularities before the universe. When the universe came into existence, these singularities were stored in ingots, called the Infinity Gems.

The Gems are free to use and are not someone’s personal property.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! While this may answer the question is there any reason why we need a 4th answer just repeating the same information?

Comment: Okay so I want to add that : 
The Infinity Stones are too powerful to be owned by someone.

In the comics, there was a cosmic being before the universe existed - Nemesis. When she died, her powers were too much to be destroyed. So they were transformed into the Infinity Gems.

In the movies, there were six singularities before the universe. When the universe came into existence, these singularities were stored in ingots, called the Infinity Gems.

The Gems are free to use and are not someone’s personal property.

Comment: So put that in your answer, it's the only interesting part that isn't in other answers.